# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object, sr1

Tags: apex

```
public class MyCustomController{

Public Account acc;

public MyCustomController(){

List<Account> lstAccount  = [select id,Name,Phone,Industry,Website,Active__c,Rating,BillingCity,Description,Fax,
ShippingCity,AnnualRevenue,BillingCountry,ShippingCountry from Account where
id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];


}

public Account getAccount() {

return acc;


}

public Pagereference saveMethod() {

update acc;

Pagereference pageRef = new ApexPages.StandardController(acc).view();

return pageRef;

}
}
```

Comment: Pleae help me out

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a line in your contructor to initialize acc. like this :

```
public MyCustomController(){

List lstAccount = [select id,Name,Phone,Industry,Website,Active__c,Rating,BillingCity,Description,Fax, ShippingCity,AnnualRevenue,BillingCountry,ShippingCountry from Account where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];

acc = 1stAccount[0];
}
```

Let me know if this helps